# Trying to write from R to Google Sheets, can't get credentials

Tags: r, googlesheets4

For the past 6+ months I read and wrote from R to Google Sheets without any issues, with the googlesheets4 package. Yesterday, all of a sudden, I started to get the 'Can't get Google credentials' error and I can't seem to find a solution to it.

I've always used gs4_auth('email address'), no other details.

I read the troubleshooting advice for gargle, I also found another thread here with suggestions, but nothing worked for me unfortunately. Here is what I get when changing gargle verbosity to 'debug':

trying `token_fetch()`
trying `credentials_service_account()`
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
trying `credentials_external_account()`
aws.ec2metadata not installed; can't detect whether running on EC2 instance
trying `credentials_app_default()`
trying `credentials_gce()`
trying `credentials_byo_oauth()`
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
trying `credentials_user_oauth2()`
Gargle2.0 initialize
attempt to access internal gargle data from: googlesheets4
adding "userinfo.email" scope
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
ReadItem: unknown type 50, perhaps written by later version of R

I don't have a clue what to change based on this info.

I also read that this sudden error may happen if the cache where gargle saves authentication data is full. But I don't find the cache. I tried to run this:

require(gargle)
gargle_oauth_sitrep()

And I get: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
ReadItem: unknown type 50, perhaps written by later version of R.

My version of R is 4.1.2 now, but before, it was 4.1.0. I updated it hoping it would solve something, but it didn't. I also reinstalled a few packages: curl, openssl, gargle. Still not working.

I am out of ideas now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found my gargle cache flies by executing
`rappdirs::user_cache_dir("gargle")` and in the R console it gave me this answer:

> Library/Caches/gargle

I deleted all files in that directory and voila the next time I used `read_sheet()` I had to login to my gmail account, click a box to allow `googlesheets4` to read and write my google sheets and now it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).